# Multiple vhosts with XAMPP 3.2.1

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I can't get a second VirtalHost to be recognized. A couple of years ago I had it working, but somewhere along the upgrade path it broke.

`localhost` is recognized. `dev` is not. I am using XAMPP v3.2.1 on Windows 7. Typing in `dev` into the browser sends me to my browser's search engine. httpd-vhosts.conf and hosts file are set up as below and I've included a dump from C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd -S. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: if I type in explicit path to the `index.php` file in the `dev` directory, it will not run as a php file, but it will just list out the contents.

Also: In my access.log, I get the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2015:09:48:12 -0700] "GET /css/ms.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/dev" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

My C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/root"
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory "D:/Website/root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        Allow from localhost
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/dev"
    ServerName dev

    <Directory "D:/Website/dev">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        Allow from localhost
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       dev
```

C:>C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd -S

```
VirtualHost configuration: *:80                is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44) 
         port 80 namevhost localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost dev (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:60)
ServerRoot: "C:/xampp/apache"
Main DocumentRoot: "D:/Website/root"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/xampp/apache/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.

The configuration was correct

The include_path was incorrect in the .htaccess file.

Firefox redirected me to my search engine but gave me a hint with a bar that said something like: "Do you want to go to dev instead" When I clicked on it, it gave me an error that I could trace to the path being the problem.

IE just redirected to my search engine.

The browsers are getting too `smart` attempting to resolve my entry by sending me to search.